# Ruby - Remove an item from an array of dictionary based off of key

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary

I have an array that stores data similarly to this:

```
people = [
   {
    'name' => "Jim",
    'car' => "Porche",
    'houseSize' => "big",
   },

   {
    'name' => "Bill",
    'car' => "Honda",
    'houseSize' => "small",
   }
]
```

How would I go about deleting an item in the array based off of a key in the dictionary. 
i.e. If I wanted to delete the dictionary with a name value of "Bill" how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
people.delete_if{|element| element['name'] == 'Bill'}
# => [{"name"=>"Jim", "car"=>"Porche", "houseSize"=>"big"}]
```

BTW: Your hashes are missing some commas.

```
people = [
  {
    'name' => "Jim",
    'car' => "Porche",
    'houseSize' => "big"
  },
  {
    'name' => "Bill",
    'car' => "Honda",
    'houseSize' => "small"
  }
]
```